# Reactjs Lazy and Suspense - My chunk.js.map is big

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please help me. My chunk.js.map is big 3MB and I try use lazy and Suspense

How correct way?

```
import React, { Component, Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Main from './pages/main';
import AboutUs from './pages/about-us';
const Orders = lazy(() => import('./pages/profile/orders'));
const Settings = lazy(() => import('./pages/profile/settings'));

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="app">
          <Header />
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
              <Route path="/about-us" component={AboutUs} />
              <Route path="/profile/orders" component={Orders} />
              <Route path="/profile/settings" component={Settings} />
            </Switch>
          </Suspense>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

or

```
import React, { Component, Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Main from './pages/main';
import AboutUs from './pages/about-us';
const Orders = lazy(() => import('./pages/profile/orders'));
const Settings = lazy(() => import('./pages/profile/settings'));

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="app">
          <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
              <Route path="/about-us" component={AboutUs} />
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
              <Route path="/profile/orders" component={Orders} />
              <Route path="/profile/settings" component={Settings} />
          </Suspense>
            </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In both cases, after assembly, I also get one large 3MB file and additionally three separate files. It is right?

I suppose that after the implementation of lazy loading, I should not see a large file in the assembly? should I only see three parts files?

Thank you.

Comment: Try this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/analyzing-the-bundle-size/ and share your result (screenshot) please.

Comment: This is full files screenshot.  https://disk.yandex.ru/d/oWFnZOxJ4pETwg  For some reason, in the assembly, I again see one large file and already several small files ... Now this large file is not required? And which of my options is the correct code or does it matter?

Comment: main.chunk.js is ~350kb it is normal. Where is 3mb file?

Comment: Maybe it is about development release? Try build and serve and check again. And sometimes chrome adds some extension's libraries. Can you send a network screenshot which are only js files.

Comment: please see my build - https://disk.yandex.ru/i/nCb6MXKvX5WY4g

Comment: i use - npm run build... and i get more files and ONE BIG FILE... How can I make serve ?

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

serve -s build // Or npx serve -s build // After that please share your network tab. Like this: https://prnt.sc/HGJZxMMi0W-p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243868/discussion-between-mehmetdemiray-and-vlad).

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/CS9ZwXO-EfFEEw

Comment: Content Scripts are about chrome extensions like inpage.bundle.js. Your js file sizes are normal and also your code is correct. No problem.

Comment: And why then is this large file present in the build? Is it not being used? 2.ab2749e9.chunk.js.map - 3MB...